# Cannot convert value of type 'DataResponse<Any>' to expected argument type 'Data'

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm making a simple post request to a site which sends back JSON that looks something like this:

```
{
    Account = "blah blah";
    Password = "blah blah";
}
```

This is the request.

```
@IBAction func submitButtonClicked(_ sender: Any){
                AF.request("https://companywebsite.com", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:JSONEncoding.default)
                .responseJSON{ response in
                    let json = try? JSON(data: response)
                }
}
```

I'm getting the following compilation error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'DataResponse<Any>' to expected argument type 'Data'
```

I'm using Alamofire to send the request and SwiftyJSON to parse it. I've never used Swift or either library before so I'm really struggling to see what I need to do to fix this.

I want to pull the account and password out to be stored in separate variables. I tried following other tutorials but I've had no success. If someone could help me out I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `responseData` instead of `responseJSON`

```
AF.request("https://companywebsite.com", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseData { response in 
   guard let data = response.data else { return }  
   let json = try? JSON(data:data)
   if let acc = json?["Account"].string {
     print(acc)
   }
   if let pass = json?["Password"].string {
     print(pass)
   }
}
```

Other variant

```
Alamofire.request("https://companywebsite.com", method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding:JSONEncoding.default)
    .responseJSON { response in
    let json = try? JSON(response.result.value!)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Sh_Khan, how do I now go about pulling the account and password from 'json' using SwiftyJson?

Comment: can you post expected response json structure

Comment: the first bit of code in my question is exactly what the JSON looks like, just long random strings instead of "blah blah"